# How to set imageView image from URL

Tags: java, android, icons

I need to set image from URL into imageView. I found few solutions, but non of them is working for me.

Could somebody help me, please?

Comment: "I found few solutions, but non of them is working for me" -- we cannot help you with any of that without a [mcve]. In general, most Android developers use [an image-loading library](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/46).

Answer (score 2):

First you need to declare this variable:

```
Bitmap bmp;
```

And then add this code:

```
String imageUrl = "URL";
                InputStream in = new URL(imageUrl).openStream();
                bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);

ImageView img_results_experience = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.img_results_experience);
                    img_id.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

It works for me!!

Comment: can you share how you were able to run this code? I keep getting an exception that it can't run on main thread

Answer (score 1):

You Can Use Picasso http://square.github.io/picasso/ a great library for loading images from the internet into imageview

Answer (score 1):

I recommended use https://github.com/bumptech/glide . It is very easy to use.

```
Glide.with(this).load(URL_TO_IMAGE).into(imageView);
```

But, not forget add dependencies:

```
repositories {
  mavenCentral() // jcenter() works as well because it pulls from Maven Central
}

dependencies {
  compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
  compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.0'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use glide library:

in your gradle:

```
dependencies {
  compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
  compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.0'
}
```

in your activity/fragment:

```
// For a simple view:
@Override public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  ...
  ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.my_image_view);

  Glide.with(this).load("YOUR URL").into(imageView);
}

// For a simple image list:
@Override public View getView(int position, View recycled, ViewGroup container) {
  final ImageView myImageView;
  if (recycled == null) {
    myImageView = (ImageView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_image_view, container, false);
  } else {
    myImageView = (ImageView) recycled;
  }

  String url = myUrls.get(position);

  Glide
    .with(myFragment)
    .load(url)
    .centerCrop()
    .placeholder(R.drawable.loading_spinner)
    .crossFade()
    .into(myImageView);

  return myImageView;
}
```